# Ошибка при обмене ЕГАИС

Tags: 1с

На компьютере идет обмен ЕГАИС по всем узлам. В большинстве обмен проходит нормально, на некоторых - нет

Именно с одним обмен не проходит с такой ошибкой

C:\Windows\system32>curl http://(тут айпи узла):8080

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset

УТМ работает нормально

Конфигурация "Управление торговлей", редакция 10.3 (10.3.21.2), база распределенная, если это чем-то поможет)

Отредактировал)

Comment: Установите бесплатную программу "трезвый декларант". Она тоже умеет обмениваться с ЕГАИС. Это позволит вам выявить причину ошибки

Comment: Мало вводных. Конфигурация, построение узлов и пр.

Comment: Отредактировал)

Comment: @АлексейМакаров у вас нет связи с этим узлом. Проверьте антивирус или брандмауэр ( firewall ) windows. УТМ работает, но пакеты от 1С не могут дойти до УТМ ( даже, если они установлены на одной и той же машине )